# Windows Core Audio Api get all supported formats on capture device

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

I would like to enumerate all supported formats on Capture device in device Properties -> Advanced -> DefaultFormat section.

I would like to use Windows Core Audio Api to do so, however I can't really find suitable interface that I could use to read those formats.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370858(v=vs.85).aspx#

Any idea which interface would provide me with such functionality?

Comment: please see my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/50396224/307093, it does answer exactly this question but in very non-obvious way

Answer (score 4):

There is the [IMMDeviceEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371399(v=vs.85).aspx) interface which can help you to obtain pointer to the [IMMDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371395(v=vs.85).aspx) you need (`IMMDevice` interface represents an audio endpoint device: render or capture):

- you can use [IMMDeviceEnumerator::EnumAudioEndpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371400(v=vs.85).aspx) method to get all active capture devices in the system, or
- you can call [IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDefaultAudioEndpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371401(v=vs.85).aspx) to obtain pointer to the default capture device.

Anyway, when you have the pointer to the IMMDevice you need to look up supported formats for, you can get the pointer to the [IAudioClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370865(v=vs.85).aspx) interface using [IMMDevice::Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371405(v=vs.85).aspx) method. `IAudioClient` interface allows you to check if the device supports an audio format or not (method [IAudioClient::IsFormatSupported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370876(v=vs.85).aspx), audio format is described by [WAVEFORMATEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970(v=vs.85).aspx) structure). Unfortunately, right now there is no method in Core Audio API which returns a list of supported formats by the device, so you will need to enumerate possible values of WAVEFORMATEX members structure and check if every format supported by device by yourself.

But you can get the format that user did select in the DefaultFormat section by using IMMDevice property store ([IMMDevice::OpenPropertyStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371412(v=vs.85).aspx)) and then checking for the `PKEY_AudioEngine_DeviceFormat` key (here is the description: [MSDN: PKEY_AudioEngine_DeviceFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316580(v=vs.85).aspx)).

It would be useful to read:

- [MSDN: Device Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370811(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSDN: Device Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370812(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSDN: Audio Endpoint Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370794(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: About the IAudioClient::IsFormatSupported solution, you need to provide the AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE flag. Without this flag the audio client will support more input format than the audio device can support.